# Why does this PHP cUrl not apply the correct authentication header?

Tags: php, curl, header

I am trying to use the files.com API [here](https://developers.files.com/?shell--json#authentication-with-api-key). I cannot get it to authenticate. The response I keep getting is 'bool(false)'

I need to add an api key to my header. Using PHP I have attempted this:

```
<?php
$key = '1234567890';
$domain = 'myDomain';
$url ="https://$domain.files.com/api/rest/v1/users.json";
$auth=['X-FilesAPI-Key'=> $key];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,[
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $auth,
]);

$content = curl_exec($ch);


$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

any suggestions to get this working would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use https. The reason it didn't work is because you need something extra for https to work: The option `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false`.

Comment: Jesus Christ that worked. I've been smashing my keyboard into my head for hours

Comment: That's normal, if you don't know you don't know. Looking at a lot of examples can help, but this is indeed a tricky one.

Comment: Uhhh disabling SSL verification is a _terrible_ fix. If it only works with verification turned off then either the remote side has an invalid certificate, or your local CA certificates are broken. Seeing as files.com uses LetsEncrypt and they've recently had some changes to their CA root that break on outdated installs, I'm going to wager that you need to update your CA certs.